# address link to the same destination with and without modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

here are two links that should lead to the same page. With the first link, the page that is landed on should be opened normally and with the second, the modal should open automatically when the page is loaded. is that possible? here it is installed in a page and the link is provided with an anchor that can possibly trigger the function.

```js
$(window).on('load', function () {
  $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  $('.modal').addClass('is-visible').modal('show');
});

$("document").ready(function () {
  $(".modal-toggle").click(function () {
    $('.modal').removeClass('is-not-visible');
    $('.modal').addClass('is-visible');
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
  });

  $(".modal-close").click(function () {
    $('.modal').removeClass('is-visible');
    $('.modal').addClass('is-not-visible');
    $('body').css('overflow', 'scroll');
  });

});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 4em auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  fill: currentcolor;
}
.modal {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10000; /* 1 */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.modal.is-visible {
  visibility: visible;
}
.modal.is-not-visible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
.modal-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.8);
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0s linear 0.3s, opacity 0.3s;
}
.modal.is-visible .modal-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.modal-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  left: 50%;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: -35%;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1.5em hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.35);
}
.modal-transition {
  transition: all 0.3s 0.12s;
  transform: translateY(-10%);
  opacity: 0;
}
.modal.is-visible .modal-transition {
  transform: translateY(0);
  opacity: 1;
}
.modal-header {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.modal-close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  color: #aaa;
  border: 0;
}
.modal-close:hover {
  color: #777;
}
.modal-heading {
  font-size: 1.125em;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.modal-content > *:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.modal-content > *:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@latest/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>

<svg display="none" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="768" height="800" viewBox="0 0 768 800"><defs><g id="icon-close"><path class="path1" d="M31.708 25.708c-0-0-0-0-0-0l-9.708-9.708 9.708-9.708c0-0 0-0 0-0 0.105-0.105 0.18-0.227 0.229-0.357 0.133-0.356 0.057-0.771-0.229-1.057l-4.586-4.586c-0.286-0.286-0.702-0.361-1.057-0.229-0.13 0.048-0.252 0.124-0.357 0.228 0 0-0 0-0 0l-9.708 9.708-9.708-9.708c-0-0-0-0-0-0-0.105-0.104-0.227-0.18-0.357-0.228-0.356-0.133-0.771-0.057-1.057 0.229l-4.586 4.586c-0.286 0.286-0.361 0.702-0.229 1.057 0.049 0.13 0.124 0.252 0.229 0.357 0 0 0 0 0 0l9.708 9.708-9.708 9.708c-0 0-0 0-0 0-0.104 0.105-0.18 0.227-0.229 0.357-0.133 0.355-0.057 0.771 0.229 1.057l4.586 4.586c0.286 0.286 0.702 0.361 1.057 0.229 0.13-0.049 0.252-0.124 0.357-0.229 0-0 0-0 0-0l9.708-9.708 9.708 9.708c0 0 0 0 0 0 0.105 0.105 0.227 0.18 0.357 0.229 0.356 0.133 0.771 0.057 1.057-0.229l4.586-4.586c0.286-0.286 0.362-0.702 0.229-1.057-0.049-0.13-0.124-0.252-0.229-0.357z"></path></g></defs></svg>

<!--navigation to the side-->
<div><a href="#">to the side</a></div>
<div class="wp-block-button modal-toggle"><a href="#landing" class="wp-block-button__link">to the side with modal</a></div>

<!--on the landing page-->
<div class="modal">
  <div class="modal-overlay modal-toggle modal-close"></div>
  <div class="modal-wrapper modal-transition">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button class="modal-close modal-toggle">
      <svg class="icon-close icon" viewBox="0 0 32 32">
        <use xlink:href="#icon-close"></use>
      </svg>
      </button>
       </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <div class="modal-content">
        text
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `landing` the current page you are on, or another one?

Comment: the link (1 and 2) leads to another page. this should be displayed once with and once without modal.

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have those two links:

```html
<a href="/landing">link 1</a>
<a href="/landing?showModal">link 2</a>
```

Using something like a parameter (`showModal` or whatever you want), you can then run a function on the landing to check if the parameter exists.
If it does, then you show the modal, if not, you do nothing.

In the landing page:

```js
$(document).on("ready", function(){
  // get the current url parameters
  const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
  
  if(urlParams.has("showModal")){
    // the parameter exists, trigger modal
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
  }
});
```